# How to display YouTube search API response in UI text view?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, youtube

I am creating a project where I have to display the YouTube search API response in a UI Text View when a button is clicked. Now I am getting the response in console.
1) How to display it as a JSON response.
2) How to display it in UI text view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zf79Ns8_oY")else {
            return
        }

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in

            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }

            if let jsondata = data {
                print(jsondata)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your response text

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for that:

Parse Response using JSONSerialization and set required value to textview text.

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zf79Ns8_oY")else {
       return
    }

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
         guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

         do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
            let text = json["KEY"] as? String
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
               self.YOURTEXTVIEW.text = text
            }
         } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
         }
    }
    task.resume()
```

maybe it is helpful.

Comment: I am getting an error (cannot assign a value of [String] to type String) at the line  self.YOURTEXTVIEW.text = text. please help me resolving this. Thank you!